# Is it bad to keep updating the same row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm using SQL Server to store several bits of information about each user. Some items (e.g. user name/password) will rarely change, but other items with change as much as once every few seconds (e.g. longitude/latitude).

I expect this system to be in use for the most of the working day, by a few hundered users. So 
on the order of 10,000 updates per user, per day, to this table.

Are they downsides to storing the continually changing information and the mostly static information in the same row? Should I keep the static information in one table, and changing information in another table?

Comment: I know this doesn't exactly answer the question but is there any need for so many write requests? Could you not use some form of difference trigger on whether or not to write to help reduce workload?

Comment: @Hawxby, that's a very good point. Hopefully that would have occurred to me soon enough :) Regardless of whatever else I decide to do, I'll be doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep all information in one table, so long as it logically belongs together. You are risking locking on user rows this way, though optimistic locking should work most of the time.

However, you should only update the fields that do update. If you have such separate needs for the different data items on the table you should write specialized data access an update routines for those.

The benefit is that you are only transferring required data from/to the database, which will reduce latency and load on the network, clients and database.

Answer (score 3):

You potentially could have an issue when scaling up in the current solution when updates and logins are happening at the same time.  The performance for logins may reduce or you may even face locking if you're using sloppy SELECT * statements.

If updating the latitude/longitude is completely dynamic from several sources you should definitely consider storing it in a new table and even possibly making a new row for each update.  If multiple sources are constantly updating the same row you will definitely face performance/locking concerns.  Creating a new row may seem counterintuitive, but it will allow you to induct data from many sources nearly simultaneously and query that data with a time stamp or similar to find the latest update while still keeping the update queries very lean and fast.  Pruning could be automatic and quick by timestamp.

Comment: Each user will only be updating a single row, and only that user (i.e. one device) will be updating that row - so there shouldn't be any locking issues there.

Answer (score 1):

If the column(s) you update are part of the clustering index (assuming one exists), you're going to be causing quite a lot of overhead for SQL server as it rearranges the table/index structure to maintain the clustering sequence. If they are part of a non-clustered index, overhead is incurred to maintain the index structure.

In both cases, statistics come into play as well. Your statistics may well get out of date, thus causing queries/stored procedures to come up with sub-optimal execution plans: you'll probably wind up running update statistics more often than you might otherwise.

Updating fixed-length columns that don't participate in an index should happen in place as the size of the data row doesn't change. Updating variable-length or nullable columns that don't participate in an index may cause page splits as the length of the data row changes (not to mention the index maintenance overhead caused by the page split).

Answer (score 1):

If you keep overwriting the LAT/LON with the current values, you're losing potentially valuable/useful data. Better, I think, to simply insert a new row into PersonLocation table:

```
       id  autoincrementing integer
       personid  int  fk references persons(id)  [indexed non-unique to speed queries on person location history)
       lat   float
       lon   float
       asof  datetime  default getdate()
```

EDIT: If you need to get current location often, you might consider a composite index on (personid, datetime).

Comment: +1 There has to some law somewhere that says if there is a database with frequently changing information, eventually users will want a history.

Comment: This is good advice as long as there is a viable business use for this time series information and as long as storage size isn't an issue.

Comment: @Joel: floats and ints don't take up much room, and often the usefulness of data isn't always apparent today. But there could be a lot more users than the OP envisions, so your point is well taken. I am assuming the users have no problem with their current location being tracked  and so no problem with location history. Other good advice would be to get the users' permission to track their location.

Answer (score 1):

10,000 updates per day is not something you will ever have to worry about.  10,000 updates a minute might start to be a concern.  Model your database to keep it simple and don't try to be fancy with the model for performance reasons.  Oded's advice about only updating the columns that are being changed is sound, no matter what your update volume is because you still want to be respectful of bandwidth, no matter how often you are updating.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the usage of the applications accessing this database, you could run into locking issues if you intend to update that single record that often.  Additionally, for the sake of sanity, maintenance, and scalability you'll likely want to look at [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).